# Is it possible to log the first line of the response in apache?

Tags: apache, tomcat, access-log

We have an Tomcat server where we're trying to log the HTTP version which the response is sent with. We've seen a few times that it seems to be HTTP/0.9, which kills the content (not supported I guess?). We would like to get some stats on this by using the access log in apache. However, since the header line for this isn't prefixed by anything, we cannot use the %{xxx}o logging.

Is there a way to get this?

An example:

Response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 This application is not currently available
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1090
Date: Wed, 12 May 2010 12:53:16 GMT
Connection: close
```

And we'd like the catch *HTTP/1.1* (alternatively, *HTTP/1.1 503 This application is not currently available*.

Is this possible? We do not have access to the application being served, so we need to do this either as a Java filter, or in the tomcat access log - Preferably in the access log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>` in server.xml writes out the request and response headers for each request.

Example:

```
19-May-2010 12:26:18 org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve invoke
INFO:           protocol=HTTP/1.1
```